# Is there a way to align the title with the y-axis label in python plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I hope someone had a similar problem and can help me.

At the moment I build a dashoard with Dash. Therefore I made some graphs with plotly in python and they look almost perfect. My last problem is that I cannot align the graph title with the y-axis title.
Let me picture this for you:

```
 ____________________________
|  tttttttt                  |
|     gggggggggggggggg  lll  |
|  y  gggggggggggggggg  lll  |
|  y  gggggggggggggggg  lll  |
|  y  gggggggggggggggg  lll  |
|         xxx                |
|____________________________|
```

t is title, x/y is x/y-axis label, l is the legend and g is the graph

I want to get that t always starts at the same x-position like y.

Until now I tried to the default `xref='container'` and set `x` to an specific number < 0 to hardcode the offset. This works until I use the same configuration for another graph where l is unequal 3 "l" long. Because of this, the graph gets moved to the left and my title alignment is crashed, because I hardcoded it. Sure, I could hardcode it for each graph, but at the end there will be over hundreds of graphs so this is no real solution I think about.
Next I thought about using `xref='paper'` and moving the title with a negative number for `x` to the left because I know the space between graph and y-axis label and I also know the height of y. The problem here is that `x` is not allowed to be negative to move it to the left.

Hopefully someone can help me to solve this problem.

Here is a MWE where you can see that the y-axis label moves to the left.

MWE:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

def set_layout(fig, title:str):

    fig.update_layout(
        title={'font_size':20, 'text': title, 'x':0.0075},
        margin=dict(pad=3, t=80, l=100, r=100, b=80),
        legend={'font_size':15, 'title_font_size':18},
        showlegend=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='this is a x axis label', title_font=dict(size=18), tickfont=dict(size=15))
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='this is a y axis label', title_font=dict(size=18), tickfont=dict(size=15))
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="short legend", x=["a", "b"], y=[2, 1]))
    set_layout(fig, title='this is a title and is perfectly aligned with y axis label')
    fig.show()

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="this is a pretty long legend that moves the graph to the left this is a pretty long legend that moves the graph to the left this is a pretty long legend that moves the graph to the left this is a pretty long legend that moves the graph to the left", x=["a", "b"], y=[2, 1]))
    set_layout(fig, title='this is a title but its not more aligned because the legend got bigger')
    fig.show()
```